# Multiple if statement only first IF works in C#

Tags: c#

I Have five labels contains different clock "hh:MM" and each one should blink when realtime is equalts to each label clock. The first if statement works fine but not other if conditon and statements. I tryed different method with no luck but whenever I change the name of condition it works but only one each time. what about a timer for each condition? should that works and if so would'nt that create overloads?
This is the code:

```
public partial class FrMain : Form
{
    private const int _blinkFrequency = 250;
    private const int _maxNumberOfBlinks = 5;
    private int _blinkCount = 0;

    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TmrAlarm.Interval = _blinkFrequency;
        TmrAlarm.Start();

    }


private void TmrAlarm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Ftime = LblTime1.Text;
    string Dtime = LblTime2.Text;
    string Atime = LblTime3.Text;
    string Mtime = LblTime4.Text;
    string ITime = LblTime5.Text;
    string RealTime = LblDigiTime.Text;

    if (FTime == RealTime)
    {
        LblTime1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.LblTime1.Visible = !this.LblTime1.Visible;
        _blinkCount++;
        if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
        {
            LblTime1.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            TmrAlarm.Stop();
            LblTime1.Visible = true;
        }

        else if (Dtime == RealTime)
        {

            LblTime2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            this.LblTime2.Visible = !this.LblTime2.Visible;
            _blinkCount++;
            if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
            {
                LblTime2.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                TmrAlarm.Stop();
                LblTime2.Visible = true;
            }

            else if (Atime == RealTime)
            {
                LblTime3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                this.LblTime3.Visible = !this.LblTime3.Visible;
                _blinkCount++;

                if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
                {
                    LblTime3.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                    TmrAlarm.Stop();
                    LblTime3.Visible = true;
                }

                else if (MTime == RealTime)
                {
                    LblTime4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    this.LblTime4.Visible = !this.LblTime4.Visible;
                    _blinkCount++;
                    if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
                    {
                        LblTime4.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                        TmrAlarm.Stop();
                        LblTime4.Visible = true;

                    }

                    else if (Itime == RealTime)
                    {
                        LblTime5.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        this.LblTime5.Visible = !this.LblTime5.Visible;
                        _blinkCount++;

                        if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
                        {
                            LblTime5.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                            TmrAlarm.Stop();
                            LblTime5.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TmrAlarm.Stop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't completely clear where you're having the issue, but you might take the time to format your code properly. Many of the if statements are nested inside others and it isn't apparent the way you have things formatted now which may lead to confusion.

Comment: [Use your debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you have your curly braces set up where you want them to be.  Your ELSE-IF is actually nested inside your first two IFs.  Let the IDE indent your code properly and the issue becomes more apparent.

```
private void TmrAlarm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Ftime = LblTime1.Text;
        string Dtime = LblTime2.Text;
        string Atime = LblTime3.Text;
        string Mtime = LblTime4.Text;
        string ITime = LblTime5.Text;
        string RealTime = LblDigiTime.Text;

        if (FTime == RealTime)
        {
            LblTime1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            this.LblTime1.Visible = !this.LblTime1.Visible;
            _blinkCount++;
            if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
            {
                LblTime1.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                TmrAlarm.Stop();
                LblTime1.Visible = true;
            }

            if (Dtime == RealTime)
            {

                LblTime2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                this.LblTime2.Visible = !this.LblTime2.Visible;
                _blinkCount++;
                if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
                {
                    LblTime2.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                    TmrAlarm.Stop();
                    LblTime2.Visible = true;
                }

                else if (Atime == RealTime)
                {
                    LblTime3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    this.LblTime3.Visible = !this.LblTime3.Visible;
                    _blinkCount++;

                    if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
                    {
                        LblTime3.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                        TmrAlarm.Stop();
                        LblTime3.Visible = true;
                    }

                    else if (MTime == RealTime)
                    {
                        LblTime4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        this.LblTime4.Visible = !this.LblTime4.Visible;
                        _blinkCount++;
                        if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
                        {
                            LblTime4.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                            TmrAlarm.Stop();
                            LblTime4.Visible = true;

                        }

                        else if (Itime == RealTime)
                        {
                            LblTime5.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            this.LblTime5.Visible = !this.LblTime5.Visible;
                            _blinkCount++;

                            if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
                            {
                                LblTime5.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                                TmrAlarm.Stop();
                                LblTime5.Visible = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                TmrAlarm.Stop();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the `else` clause and just have each be `if`. Else only evaluates if `If` fails. If `If` succeeds, `else` won't be evaluated.

Comment: Thank you all I corrected the  brackets and now the code function correctly as I wanted. Yes Gaming Impteraix this code should detect wether LblTime.Text is equal to realtime . I have other timer that assign specified time "HH:mm" every new day then the alarm timer should  monitor the real time if equal to that  daily assigned fixed time.  My case: I have five labels with five different times assigned by other timer every single day and are different, that means five if conditions and statements and each condition has an intern condition that made things a bit complicated with brackets. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you initially uploaded the code, it had missing brackets and was not formatted correctly. Now that I'm looking at your correctly-formatted code, I have to ask whether you are still having the same problem (because I am having difficulty figuring out what your problem *is*).

Among other questions I have to ask are these...

1. Are you sure you want to detect whether the timer is EQUAL TO RealTime? If this is an alarm clock, you may want to detect whether Realtime has EXCEEDED the timer.
2. Are you sure you want the alarms to prevent one another from checking for time? With all your nested ifs, F time will prevent D time from being checked for, and so on and soforth

Solving 1 is up to you--you'd need to turn the strings into dates or other comparable forms. Solving 2 would look something like this:

```
private void TmrAlarm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Ftime = LblTime1.Text;
    string Dtime = LblTime2.Text;
    string Atime = LblTime3.Text;
    string Mtime = LblTime4.Text;
    string ITime = LblTime5.Text;
    string RealTime = LblDigiTime.Text;

    bool alarmWentOff = false;

    if (FTime == RealTime)
    {
        LblTime1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.LblTime1.Visible = !this.LblTime1.Visible;
        _blinkCount++;
        if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
        {
            LblTime1.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            TmrAlarm.Stop();
            LblTime1.Visible = true;
        }

        alarmWentOff = true;
    }

    if (Dtime == RealTime)
    {

    LblTime2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.LblTime2.Visible = !this.LblTime2.Visible;
        _blinkCount++;
        if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
        {
            LblTime2.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            TmrAlarm.Stop();
            LblTime2.Visible = true;
        }

        alarmWentOff = true;
    }

    if (Atime == RealTime)
    {
        LblTime3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.LblTime3.Visible = !this.LblTime3.Visible;
        _blinkCount++;

        if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
        {
            LblTime3.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            TmrAlarm.Stop();
            LblTime3.Visible = true;
        }

        alarmWentOff = true;
    }
    if (MTime == RealTime)
    {
        LblTime4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.LblTime4.Visible = !this.LblTime4.Visible;
        blinkCount++;
        if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
        {
            LblTime4.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            TmrAlarm.Stop();
            LblTime4.Visible = true;

        }

        alarmWentOff = true;
    }
    if (Itime == RealTime)
    {
        LblTime5.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.LblTime5.Visible = !this.LblTime5.Visible;
        blinkCount++;

        if (_blinkCount == _maxNumberOfBlinks * 30)
        {
            LblTime5.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            TmrAlarm.Stop();
            LblTime5.Visible = true;
        }

        alarmWentOff = true;
    }
    if(alarmWentOff == false)
    {
        TmrAlarm.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes Gaming your method works too, but new issue appeared : whenever I run the code in exact same alarm time it blinks 60 sec not 30 and it keeps Color.Red not LimeGreen as I wanted, somehow it does not go back to previous state. Considering if power goes off and on then app starts in the alarm time, Any Idea?

Comment: You are going to need to use breakpoints to figure out what is going on. Make sure your code is entering each block and figure out what values are inside and outside of if statements. if _maxNumberOfBlinks is too high, it will blink too long. If blinkCount is never getting reset to 0 anywhere you'll have problems. (Sometimes it best to test for >= instead of == for this reason). It may be that as long as FTime == Realtime (ie, a whole minute, 60 seconds), the timer is blinking endlessly, because blinkCount is much higher than maxBlinks *30.